# How to Use a Shared Folder in VirtualBox with AndroVM

Tags: virtualbox, android

I'm trying out [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/) and cant figure out how to access a shraed folder with VirtualBox. The instructions say it needs to be called mysdcard, which I did. But I can't find it in the android.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Could you please list the steps done for creating the shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [AndroVM Documentation](http://androvm.org/blog/androvm-documentation/):

> Beginning with the 20130222 release, VirtualBox shared folders are supported ; all the “auto-mount” shared folders configured for the VM will be mounted under the “/mnt/shared” directory.

This is working for me.