# Shared Folder in VirtualBox with Android not working

Tags: virtualbox, android, shared-folders

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/545156/how-to-use-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox-with-androvm) I am supposed to see a "Shared Folder".

Using android-x86-4.3-20130725.iso

[image]
(original picture: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/231/uewc.png)

Comment: Lucky you.




My Android-x86 Nougat has no file system access, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you get this warning when adding "Shared Folders" options in your VM?

[image: Warning VB]

Did you add "VirtualBox Guest Additions" to your Android install? That seems unlikely because according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235165/getting-vbox-guest-addtions-for-android-x86) the GA (Guest Additions) are not supported in Android. You could try to compile and install them yourself but that won't be easy.

You could also use a distro of Android with built in support for the "VB shared folders".

[AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/androvm-documentation/) has this built in support as of version 20130222.

> Beginning with the 20130222 release, VirtualBox shared folders are supported ; all the “auto-mount” shared folders configured for the VM will be mounted in the “/mnt/shared” directory.

BTW. With the "ES Explorer", which you are using, you could also browse to a share on your network. So if you share your folder on the network you can use that.

[image: ES Explorer]

As an alternative you could use [BTSync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) to get files from your host-computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have it shared on the network it will work fine with ES Explorer.

I have a shared folder on a Windows PC in local network, which I can copy to from my Android with ES Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Use usb/flash drives. Copy files/folders to your usb drives, enable them in the guest OS (lower right hand corner) and then copy your files to the guest OS. Simple. I use it in that way. Saves me the time of uploading and downloading files.

Comment: How does this help with the original problem? The question was about VirtualBox shared folders which is not the same as transferring files with USB/flash drivers (or any other removable media for that matter). That's simply because using a shared folder does not require physical transfer of the medium and thus can be used with locations far away from each other. You might want to re-write your answer to help it properly address the problem the original question is about.

Answer (score 1):

- Configure a web server in your Host OS (I prefer xampp).
- Configure the apache server to be accessible within the lan (host ip).
- Next create a folder in C:\xampp\htdocs\consider the name as "Share".
- In Android in Virtual box, take the browser and go to your
  hostip/Share to get all the files in it (but everything is restricted
  to downloads only).

If you are a web developer, then develop a simple page for file upload and keep in that directory.

Comment: how can my HOST (Windows) could be accessible by the GUEST (Android) through just IP,... without bridging the network...?

Comment: @gumuruh You can refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)