# Cannot copy to or from shared folders in AndroVM-VirtualBox 4.3.14

Tags: virtualbox, android

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/545156/how-to-use-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox-with-androvm) it is clearly said that shared folders are supported in VirtualBox starting from versions released in 2013. But when I try to copy any data from androvm to /mnt/shared/Androshared folder, the below error message is showing.

> libcore.io.errnoexception open failed eacces (permission denied)

I want to copy data from whatsapp to my local drives. Is there any fix for this problem or alternative method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found the answer myself. AndroVM may be outdated and discontinued but this solution remains same for shared folder of Genymotion (upgraded version of AndroVM) or any shared folder in VirtualBox.

**First thing is**

If you intend to write anything to shared folder from inside guest OS or Android Emulator, do not check the "Read-only" check box while adding shared folder path (Even if you had done you can edit later).

**Second thing is**

You are allowed to edit any changes to shared folder but it may or may not reflect inside the Android emulator or guest OS. Better if you completely shutdown or close that emulator and start again.